# How to decrease the height of a linearLayout with initial height as fill_parent

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to achieve is to implement a typical texting screen, where I have a LinearLayout initially occupying the whole screen by setting the height to be fill_parent, except a RelativeLayout containing an EditText at the bottom of the screen using android:layout_alignParentBottom.

Now, I need to display an extra RelativeLayout at the bottom of the small RelativeLayout, which should reduce the height of the LinearLayout, and push the original RelativeLayout up.

Please advise what is the best way to achieve the above scenario. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I find easier the use of RelativeLayout for cases like this.

- You can define a RelativeLayout as a container of all of them and
  place the others inside it.
- Set your LinearLayout height to "match_parent"
- Place the EditText below the LinearLayout; and the RelativeLayout,
  below the EditText; using android:layout_below

Good luck friend!